# Find and replace to prepend area code and exchange code to selected telephone numbers

Tags: excel

I need to search a worksheet and find all instances of `-nnnn` where `n` is a number. I need to find just that pattern so 888-545-0909 would NOT match as it has to be just those five characters: a dash then four numbers. An example cell is like `-5456`.

I need to then replace `-nnnn` with `888-534-nnnn`.

The problem is that some phone numbers in the spreadsheet are the last four digits but I need the area code and the exchange to be part of the number.

Comment: just a dash and 4 numbers, nothing before and after so an example cell is like -5456

Answer (score 0):

I think you are lucky the data is so consistent:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=5,"888-534"&A1,A1)
```

should work.

Comment: thanks that is a big step in the right direction. How do i do that for all cells in the whole workbook ? I assume that (A1) would jusst make the change in cell A1 ?